# Convert human readable time to epoch timestamp in Python

Tags: python, epoch

I am training to convert human readable time to epoch time. This is my test case

```
import time
text = '12.12.2020'
format = ['%d/%m/%Y','%m/%d/%Y','%d-%m-%Y','%m-%d-%Y','%d.%m.%Y','%m.%d.%Y','%d%m%Y','%m%d%Y']
for fmt in format:
        try:
            epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(text,fmt)))
            print (epoch)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('invalid input')
```

This above code prints 4 time "invalid input" then 5th line prints correct epoch value, Because my **text='12.12.2020'** input string meets 5th condition. I need to print if my "text" condition meets any of those format then print only epoch value, otherwise print "invalid input". Could anyone help me to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I'd highly suggest **not using the keyword** `format` as a variable name due to it being a built-in function from Python itself (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). This is called bad practice when assigning variable names.

---

Anyway, regarding your problem: Your approach isn't so far off - you were missing a slight change:

```
import time

format_list = ['%d/%m/%Y','%m/%d/%Y','%d-%m-%Y','%m-%d-%Y','%d.%m.%Y','%m.%d.%Y','%d%m%Y','%m%d%Y']
text = '12.1s2.2020'

for fmt in format_list:
    try:
        epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(text,fmt)))
        break
    except:
        epoch = 'invalid input'
        pass
```

This iterates through your `format_list` and tries assigning the converted time to the variable `epoch`. Instead of printing 'invalid error', as you did, I just assign it to  `epoch`, hence if the for-loop went through all eight possibilities without succeeding, `epoch` equals `'invalid input'`. However, if the statement `epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(text,fmt)))` is true the for-loop breaks, hence the last assignment, being the proper value you wanted, lasts.

You may output `epoch` via the `print()` function:

```
print(epoch)
```

The output in this case is: `1607727600`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response. It helped me.

Comment: @S.ARAVIND Did it solve your problem? Or do you have any questions regarding my answer?